# How do you load a text file into a list and then work with that list with normal list functions in Python?

Tags: python, list, file, text, nested

I am having trouble with my program. I had originally set it up to have a user enter employee information that populated a nested list, and then do things with that info. Each nested list was one employee. Worked fine. Now I am adding the ability to save the entered info as a text file, and also to load from that file. I believe we are supposed to have it run in the IDLE shell as opposed to a terminal window.

I can save the info in a text file and it comes out like this:

```
John Doe,111111111,(555)555-1212,john@john.com,$50000
Jane Doe,222222222,(444)555-1111,jane@jane.com,$50,000
```

I am loading it as such:

```
for line in open('employee_file.txt'):
    items = line.rstrip('\n').split('\t')  
    items = [item.strip() for item in items] 
    temp_load_list.append(items)
```

This gets me a nested list like this:

```
[[John Doe,111111111,(555)555-1212,john@john.com,$50000],[Jane Doe,222222222,(444)555-1111,jane@jane.com,$50,000]]...
```

This is the same structure I got when only using my user entered data, except the user entered data had single quotes around all but the second item since it was an integer. It doesnt work with all of the other functionality that I wrote for the user entered stuff so I thought, well I will add the single quotes around the certain items, and type each as a string or integer as needed...but I can not address a single item in this list!

If I try to print the first item in the first list, Id expect `"John Doe"` to be returned.

```
print('This should be first item of first list:',temp_load_list[0][0])
```

Instead what I get is:

```
John Doe,111111111,(555)555-1212,john@john.com,$50000
```

The brackets are gone, but that's it. If I try to break that down with a for loop, I get each character streaming out vertically. So, I am not able to change any of the specific items, or pick them out to populate a display field like "Employee 1 Name:"

I'd like to have a solution that will work in the IDLE editor environment, so any imported modules would have to do that.

Why is the list I make from a text file not behaving like a list?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions!
Neil

Comment: It's a CSV file, use the `csv` module to read and parse it.

Comment: Your fields are separated by `,`, why are you using `split('\t')`? It should be `split(',')`.

Comment: So is CSV the default format for saving a text file then? I am saving the file like this: filename = 'employee_file.txt'
    with open(filename, 'a+') as f:
        for sublist in list_emp_info:
            line = "{"''"},{},{},{},{}\n".format(sublist[0], sublist[1],sublist[2],sublist[3],sublist[4])
            f.write(line)     Which as I am looking at it is adding the commas, ooof. Duh. Still, Ive worked with csv's before with mailing lists so I will dig into the CSV angle. Thanks!

Comment: There's no "default format", files can be saved in whatever format you want. But the file you showed happens to be a CSV.

Comment: You're writing the file with commas between each field, so you need to split it the same way.

Comment: I guess I made it as such with my save method, see my edit above, thanks again

Comment: You should use the csv module when saving the file, too.

Comment: `csvfile = csv.writer(f); csvfile.writerows(list_emp_info)`

Comment: Ahhh. The dangers of using snippets of code from elsewhere without understanding all it does and why. I think the first time I saved the file it was a mess, so I was looking for a formatting option, Thanks so much Barmar, I have a lot to work with now.